# evento para display:block em imagem

Tags: jquery, css3

Tenho 3 `imagens` em uma `ul`.

Uma `imagem` por `li`. Portanto, 3 `li's`.

Elas estão todas com `display:none`. Exceto a primeira.

Com `jQuery`, eu clico em um `botão` com `numeração` e as `imagens` vão aparecendo (`display: block`) à medida em que vou apertando o botão que carrega o `id` da `imagem` `x`, enquanto as demais vão recebendo `display: none`.

Existe algum `evento` que permita aplicar um `efeito` no momento em que a `imagem` receber o `display: block`?

Comment: Nativo, não, mas você pode emitir um evento personalizado no seu código quando você altera o valor do `style.display` no JavaScript. Tem como postar o seu código?

Comment: Qual tipo de efeito, tipo fadein e fadeout?

Comment: Pode usar fadeIn.

Comment: Código completo em uma só página: http://hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/slide.php